# Modal not coming up when I click

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to put a modal in where when a user clicks something from a list of names it will pop up and have more info on the item.

```
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import ModalDialog from "react-bootstrap/ModalDialog";
import ModalHeader from "react-bootstrap/ModalHeader";
import "./style.css";


class Home extends React.Component {
    state = {
        news: [],
        conditions: [],
        symptoms: [],
        modalShow: [],
        selectedSymptom: []
    }
```

then in the `render() { return (` I have:

```
                            <Col className="cond">
                                <div className="doubleCol">
                                    {this.state.conditions
                                        .filter(condition => !this.state.selectedSymptom.length || condition.symptoms.includes(this.state.selectedSymptom))
                                        .map(item => (
                                            <div>
                                                <ListItem key={item.ObjectID} onClick={() => this.setState({ modalShow: true })}>
                                                    {item.name}
                                                </ListItem>

                                                <Modal animation={false} centered>
                                                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                                                        <Modal.Title> {item.name}</Modal.Title>
                                                    </Modal.Header>
                                                    <Modal.Body> {item.description}</Modal.Body>
                                                    <Modal.Footer>
                                                        {item.link}
                                                        <Button onClick={() => this.setState({ modalShow: false })}>Close</Button>
                                                    </Modal.Footer>
                                                </Modal>
                                            </div>
                                        ))}
                                </div>
                                {/* Pull in names of conditions here. Each name should be clickable and call up full info on that condition */}
                            </Col>
```

The problem is when I click an item on the list exactly Bupkis happens

Answer (score 0):

on click it is setting the state to -> modalShow: false

try true.

Comment: that is in the close button of the modal. But i did try commenting it out just in case and no difference